# Mule 4 - Problem With Deploy with Maven to CloudHub

Tags: maven, mule, dataweave, mule4

I have the follow error when i try to used maven to deploy on CloudHub:

```
Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:2.3.13:test (test) on 
project gglobal-reverselogic-notifications: Build Failed: There was an error running M 
Unit tests -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:2.3.13:test
```

this is my pom file:

```
<app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>
<mule.maven.plugin.version>3.8.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
<munit.version>2.3.14</munit.version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-objectstore-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-mongodb-connector</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.7</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.13</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.13</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.weave</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertions</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

i was reading the blog in the internet and it's saw that i need to put the follow dependency in my pom file

```
com.mulesoft.wave
```

but when i put the dependency, it show a error in Anypoint Studion, it's doesn't exists...

Currently use the Version: Mule 4.4.0 and Maven: 3.8.6, also i change the Mule to 4.3.0, but it show me the same problem.

Could you please help me?

Best regards!!!

Comment: what dependency are you talking about "com.mulesoft.wave"? it is not in the dependency list. When you talk about a dependency mention the complete coordinates. Where did you read that you need it? What happens if you don't add it? Note that 4.3.0 and 4.4.0 are Mule versions, not some "framework". What is the version of the Mule Maven Plugin?

Comment: <app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>
  <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.8.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
  <munit.version>2.3.14</munit.version>

Comment: Please add the information to the question, and also include the response to my other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error doesn't happen deploying to CloudHub but in the testing phase when MUnit is executed:

```
Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:2.3.13:test (test
```

The error doesn't provide details of what went wrong, however the dependency that you seem to have added is most likely the DataWeave library for Mule 3.x:

```xml
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
```

This is not a dependency that you should add to a Mule 4 application project. There is no reason to add it to your Mule 4 project. Just remove that dependency.